# Load a HTML page within another HTML page as a popup

Tags: angularjs

I need to display or load a HTML page within another HTML page on a button click.I need this in a popup with the main html page as the background..pls can any tell me proper suggestions.

Comment: post what you tryed ...

Comment: You could use Bootstrap modal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Facebox jQuery plugin. It does pretty much exactly what you're asking for. For example you can have a link like this to some remote page like so

```
<a href="remote.html" rel="facebox">text</a>
```

then just call the facebox plugin when your content is loaded like so

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
});
```

and your content will render in a modal window. You can also take a look at Fancybox or ThickBox which provide very similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try using [windows.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) function.

**for Example**

```
 var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
 var URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?mini=true&amp;url=" + location.href;
 var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);
```